# Is there an official list of known Wix Directory Id values?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to create a Wix installer, where I need to create some items on the desktop.
The one for all users (C:\Users\Public\Desktop on Windows 10) is restricted, so I'd like to create it on the current user's desktop (C:\Users<currentuser>\Desktop).

However, all the examples of Wix installers interacting with the desktop use the DesktopFolder value (which is the all users one):

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop">
        ... [my stuff for the desktop goes here]
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

… where DesktopFolder seems like a well-known identifier for a system special folder.

Wix [documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directory.html) says nothing.

Is there an official list where I could find the id for the desktop folder of the currently logged on user?

Comment: The list I was looking for is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa372057(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
but MAQ678 provided the real answer.

Comment: WiX is merely a way of building Windows Installer (.MSI) databases.  The MSFT SDK documentation for that platform service can be found here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the **InstallScope** of your installer (**PerUser** or **PerMachine** ).

If you are using PerMachine, you will get public desktop folder.

And, if you are using PerUser, you will get desktop folder of that user.

You can find details about DesktopFolder [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/desktopfolder?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [here](https://docs.flexera.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/IHelpPropReference.htm)

They are not wix guideline. But, wix is based on Windows Installer.